# .htaccess 404 error page relative url

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to create a custom 404 page and i want to use in the .htaccess page the relative path of the page. But it is not working. For tha full path I am getting results. Is there any way to make the relative path to work? I have this in the .htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /notfound.php
```

Comment: Could you post your .htaccess so we can see what you are doing?

Comment: I have only this line in my .htaccess file. ErrorDocument 404 /notfound.php.

Comment: What do you mean with relative paths. Do you want to have a separate `notfound.php` file in every dir? Or do images/css not load properly in your custom 404 page?

Comment: I think there is no way to do that. I was trying to use only the name of the page(or find another solution) and not the full path because i didn't want a name of a folder to be obvious in this file. I think it works only with the full path, i didn't find any other solution. Thanks for your interest!